# Algorithm to count "Space" in text file

Tags: python

Write an algorithm in pseudocode to count the number "Space"s in
a file of text. How many comparisons does it do? What is The number of increment in the best,worst and average case?

```
file = open("info.txt","r+");

content = file.read();
sum=0
for i in content:
    if i == " ":
        sum+=1
print(sum)
```

so this is my algorithm
N - is the number of symbols in text file it includes "Space"s numbers,letters and etc.
Number of comparison is N - for every symbol we have comparison to check if its "space"
The best case for increment is 0 when text file is empty we dont have increment of sum
but I struggle with the worst and average case I would like to get some help.

Comment: worst case is every char is a whitespace, average case is (1+2+3+4+5+...+n) / n

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean by best and worst case for increment is how much we execute the increment operation.

in a file with 100 letters and no spaces we wont increment
in a file with 100 spaces we will use the increment a 100 times

but incrementing or not doesn't really matter.

what matters is that we're looping over the file.

time complexity (best, worst and average case concepts) is independent of what the value of the size of the input actually is, meaning it doesn't care if n is big or small. it's related to how the steps the algorithm takes scales with the input.

if we're gonna do 1 step for each element. it's linear therefore O(n).
if we're gonna do n steps for each input element. it's quadratic therefor O(n^2)

here it loops over the file to the end. best case, worst case is n

but look at this code for example

```
for i in content:
    if i == " ":
        break
```

the best case here is that we find a space at the beginning therefore the time it took is **1**
the worst case here is that we find a space at the very end therefore the time it took is **n**
therefore the big O notation the O(n) since we take the worst case

I hope i didn't waste your time